# Proving the inequality $1 - (1-x)^n \le \sqrt{nx}$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $n \ge 0$ an integer

Tags: inequality

Could I get a brief hint on proving the inequality
$$
1 - (1-x)^n \le \sqrt{nx} \qquad (0 \le x \le 1, \; n \text{ a nonnegative integer}) \quad ?
$$
I wasn't happy with the usual differentiation approach, even after making the replacement $x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Why weren't you happy with the "usual differentiation approach?"  Can you include in your post your work in that case?

Comment: I was hoping for some insight on how this particular relation might have been discovered (likely not just by someone differentiating function after function, but I suppose it's possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the left hand side is $\le 1$, we may assume that $\sqrt {nx}<1$.
Then $nx<\sqrt{nx}$ and from Bernoulli's inequality
$$ (1-x)^n\ge 1-nx >1-\sqrt{nx}.$$

Comment: @MathLover if $\sqrt{nx} \geq 1$, then the inequality is trivial since $1-(1-x)^n \leq 1$ for any $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence the assumption that $\sqrt{nx} <1$ brings us to the more interesting case.